# Windows - Interacting with desktop while screen is locked

Tags: windows, winapi, lockscreen

When you are connecting to Windows machine with Remote Desktop you can see and interact with desktop even though screen is locked on actual machine...

Now my question is: is it possible for your application to capture desktop (actual desktop, not lock screen) and interact with it (move mouse, click and so on...) while screen is locked (with Win+L)?

Comment: Yes, yes it is. There are a number of ways depending on what you are trying to do. What **are** you trying to do? See also: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Answer explaining hot to capture (take a snapshot of) desktop while screen is locked would be good. At least for a start.

Comment: One option is to connect using RDP, and use Ctrl+PrtSc. Are you actually trying to solve a particular problem? Or are you just experimenting to see what is possible?

Comment: I don't just want to take a screenshot I want to be able to do it programatically from application running on machine.

Comment: OK now you need to edit your question to say that: From an application running on the machine desktop, you need to take a screenshot, while the desktop is locked.